# C# ListView is not displaying database results using stored procedure and parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2017

My listview is not displaying the results when the stored procedure is ran with a parameter. The listview should show the transactions for the selected account.

The code I use works perfectly when ran with a different stored procedure and no parameters. I checked the stored procedure on the database and it works the way it should, displaying the transactions for the selected account.

```
            transactionListView.Items.Clear();
            SqlConnection sql = new SqlConnection(@"Server=.\DANIELSQL;Database=Accounts;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            sql.Open();

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("spTransactionTable_GetTransactionDetails_ByAccount", sql);
            com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AccountName", accountNameChoice.SelectedItem.ToString());

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dt.Rows[i];

                if (dr.RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
                {
                    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(dr["TransactionID"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["AccountName"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["TransactionAmount"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["Category"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["DateValue"].ToString());
                    lvi.SubItems.Add(dr["IncomeOrExpenditure"].ToString());

                    transactionListView.Items.Add(lvi);
                }
            }

            sql.Close();
```

When I run the no parameter stored procedure all the records are shown. When I run the parameterised stored procedure nothing is shown.

I tired placing a breakpoint starting on SqlDataAdapter on both stored procedures. When it gets to the for loop, on the non parameterised stored procedure it says that it is filled with 3, which is how many transactions there are. On the parameterised stored procedure it says that it is filled with 0.

Comment: It's likely a bug in your stored procedure. Also, **don't use `AddWithValue` because it gets type inference wrong**: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ - you can debug your Stored Procedure using SSMS.

Comment: I would probably try `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(accountNameChoice.SelectedItem.ToString());` to ensure you are passing the expected value in.

Comment: @ChrisMack I assume the account name is the expected value. What is appearing is the class name of where it is stored. I am not sure where to go from here.

Comment: I have posted an answer which should hopefully lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `accountNameChoice.SelectedItem.ToString()` is displaying the name of the class, you need to work out what the class is, and which property of that class represents the account name.

An example of what this might look like when you pass the value to the stored procedure:

```
((Account)accountNameChoice.SelectedItem).Name
```

This would be the case if you had a class such as:

```
public class Account
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I love you dude. That works. It displays the records and shows the right ones. Thank you. Been stuck on that problem for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Try executing your stored procedure with your input in SSMS and check if it is returning any results.

Comment: The stored procedure works fine in SSMS. It gives me my results.

Comment: Ok. I cannot comment because of my reputation above. But it looks like you have your accountNameChoice bounded to an Object. If so you have to do  
(accountNameChoice.SelectedItem as ClassName).Property  to get the value.